# Passing template parameters to base class, concise notation

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is there a more consice way to pass parameters to a base template class?

```
template <class II, class ICI>
class GraphBase : public GraphBaseOfBase<II, ICI>
{ ... };

template <>
class GraphBase<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator> :
    public GraphBaseOfBase<
        std::vector<int>::iterator,
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator>
{ ... };
```

Comment: [OT]: care with specialization over `std::vector<>::iterator` (and iterators in general) as you might have some conflict as there are not always the type you expect. (`std::vector<int>::iterator` might be an `int*` or a true class, in the same way the type of `std::set<T, Comp1>::iterator` and `std::set<T, Comp2>::iterator` might be identical, or not).

Comment: Great observation! @Jarod42, never thought about that before... New lesson to remember in code reviews..

Comment: You might use `using` to shorten the primary types used. `using vi = typename std::vector<int>::iterator; using vic = std::vector<int>::iterator;` and then `template <>
class GraphBase : public GraphBaseOfBase<vi, vic>`. but not sure it is what you want.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you can form your comment as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: why two args instead of one `container` and then `typename container::iterator`? is it really possible to use two unrelated iterator types?

Comment: @AndyT у мене є обгортка для ітератора по вектору, яка ще дещо робить, і іноді я використовую рідні ітератори вектора, а іноді цю обгортку, тому я не можу просто передати контейнер. Дякую!

Comment: @Yola: I think only English is allowed by SO rules, nevertheless was nicely surprised to read my native language here (my initial thought was it was automatically translated for some reason :) The comment says: "I have a wrapper for vector iterators with additional logic, and sometimes I use vector iterators directly, thus I cannot use `container` arg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `using` to shorten the primary types used, something like:

```
using vec_it = typename std::vector<int>::iterator;
using vec_cit = std::vector<int>::iterator;
```

and then

```
 template <>
 class GraphBase : public GraphBaseOfBase<vec_it, vec_cit>
 {
     //...
 };
```